# Get multiple select from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that show "Trafic", This table has the license plate number, origin and destination of each vehicle that has entered or left Qom province.

| id | CarPelakNumber | FromCity | ToCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00000 | Kerman | Qom |
| 1 | 11111 | Qom | Tehran |
| 2 | 22222 | Ahvaz | Qom |
| 3 | 33333 | Garmsar | Qom |
| 4 | 44444 | Saveh | Qom |
| 5 | 55555 | Karaj | Qom |
| 6 | 66666 | Semnan | Qom |
| 7 | 77777 | Qom | Karaj |
| 8 | 88888 | Kerman | Qom |
| 9 | 99999 | Kerman | Qom |
| 10 | 22222 | Qom | Tehran |
| 11 | 33333 | Qom | Hamedan |
| 12 | 66666 | Qom | Arak |
| 13 | 88888 | Qom | Fars |
| 14 | 99999 | Qom | Yasooj |

The next table is "City" that show title of other provinces except Qom province.

| id | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tehran |
| 2 | Ahvaz |
| 3 | Garmsar |
| 4 | Saveh |
| 5 | Karaj |
| 6 | Semnan |
| 7 | Hamedan |
| 8 | Kerman |
| 9 | Arak |
| 10 | Fars |
| 11 | Yasooj |

I want to find all the cars that only entered and did not leave Qom province.
Sample SQL code:

```
    Select * from Trafic
       where FromCity in (select City from City) and
             ToCity='Qom' and
             ToCity not in (select City from City)
```

| id | CarPelakNumber | FromCity | ToCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00000 | Kerman | Qom |
| 4 | 44444 | Saveh | Qom |
| 5 | 55555 | Karaj | Qom |

I want to find all the cars that just left Qom province and did not enter it.
The sample SQL code is:

```
    Select * from Trafic
       where FromCity='Qom' and and
             FromCity not in (select City from City) and
             ToCity in (select City from City)
```

| id | CarPelakNumber | FromCity | ToCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | Qom | Tehran |
| 7 | 77777 | Qom | Karaj |

I want to find all the cars that entered and left Qom province.
The sample SQL code is:

```
   WITH T1 AS
    (
        Select * from Traffic
            where FromCity in (select City from City) and
                  ToCity='Qom' 
    )
    , T2 as
    (
        Select * from Traffic
            where FromCity='Qom' and
                  ToCity in (select City from City)
    )
    select * from T1,T2
      where T1.CarPelakNumber=T2.CarPelakNumber
```

But the above code has a problem and I do not give exactly the output I need and it gives the wrong answer.

| id | CarPelakNumber | FromCity | ToCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 22222 | Ahvaz | Qom |
| 3 | 33333 | Garmsar | Qom |
| 6 | 66666 | Semnan | Qom |
| 8 | 88888 | Kerman | Qom |
| 9 | 99999 | Kerman | Qom |
| 10 | 22222 | Qom | Tehran |
| 11 | 33333 | Qom | Hamedan |
| 12 | 66666 | Qom | Arak |
| 13 | 88888 | Qom | Fars |
| 14 | 99999 | Qom | Yasooj |

Comment: what is your desired output? Could you please add that in your question

Comment: Can you please mention your dbms? Oracle SQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, whatever. That allows us to give you even better answers by using db-specific functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by practicing and repeating:
SQL code for find all the cars that only entered and did not leave Qom province:

```
    ;WITH t AS
    (
        Select * from Trafic
                 where FromCity='Qom' and
                       ToCity in (select City from City)
    )
        SELECT *
           FROM Trafic
               where FromCity in (select City from City) and
                     ToCity='Qom' and
                     ToCity not in (select City from City) and
                     CarPelakNumber not in (select CarPelakNumber from t)
```

SQL code for find all the cars that just left Qom province and did not enter it:

```
  ;WITH t AS
    (
        Select * from Trafic
                 where FromCity in (select City from City) and
                       ToCity='Qom'
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM Trafic
           where FromCity='Qom' and
                 FromCity not in (select City from City) and
                 ToCity in (select City from City) and
                 CarPelakNumber not in (select CarPelakNumber from t)
```

And SQL code for find all the cars that entered and left Qom province:

```
;WITH T1 AS
    (
        Select * from Trafic
            where FromCity in (select City from City) and
                  ToCity ='Qom' 
    )
    , T2 as
    (
        Select * from Trafic
            where FromCity='Qom'  and
                  ToCity in (select City from City)
    )
    SELECT *
      from Trafic
              where CarPelakNumber in (select CarPelakNumber from T1) and
                    CarPelakNumber in (select CarPelakNumber from T2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find all the cars that only entered and did not leave Qom
> province.

```
Select * from Trafic where ToCity='Qom' and FromCity <> 'Qom';
```

> I want to find all the cars that just left Qom province and did not
> enter it.

```
Select * from Trafic where FromCity='Qom' and ToCity <> 'Qom';
```

In the above two statements you really only need the fist clause respectively. It seems that a car always has `Qom` either in `FromCity` or in `ToCity`.

> I want to find all the cars that entered and left Qom province.

```
Select * from Trafic where FromCity='Qom' and ToCity = 'Qom';
```

This does not make sense looking at the data, but you said `and` - so that is how you would do it.

I am aware that is is not very helpful as this does not solve the underlying problems of you question. But I hope it gives you the opportunity to reflect on it a bit more. Please feel free to improve you question.

Update:

Looking at your question I realized that the last statement was meant to be maybe like follows:

```
Select * from Trafic where FromCity='Qom' union Select * from Trafic where ToCity = 'Qom';
```

Comment: Hi,Unfortunately, your code does not display exactly what I asked for and showed in the tables in my question.

Comment: Please try to update your question. I referred to the text that you wrote, which did not really relate to the "tables" in the question. I mean `I want to find all the cars that only entered and did not leave Qom province.` - my feeling is that you want us to know that a car is identified by the second column - can you confirm that?